# Retrieving image url from Firebase Storage and placing inside an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageview

When a user registers, the profile pic is saved to firebase storage. What I am trying to do is retrieve it (profile pic) from "Users/Drivers" node in firebase and place it in an imageView in an AlertDialog.

What is wrong with this code that it isn't doing what it should?

```
DatabaseReference driverArrivedRef = rootRef.child("Users/Drivers").child(driverId);
    driverArrivedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // get driver profile pic from database 'Users/Drivers'
            for (DataSnapshot ss : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                String imageUrl = ss.child("photoUrl").toString();

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface
                        .OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                //Yes button clicked
                                Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "Confirmed!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                isRiderInVehicle();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                break;

                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "Not Confirmed, Try Again.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RiderHome.this);
                getImageBitmapFromURL(context, imageUrl); // code below
                builder.setTitle("Driver Has Arrived")
                        .setMessage("Please proceed to vehicle.")
                        .setPositiveButton("CONFIRM", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", dialogClickListener);

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                alert.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**getImageBitmapFromURL()**

```
public static Bitmap getImageBitmapFromURL(final Context context, final String imageUrl){
    Log.e(TAG, "getImageBitmapFromURL");

    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    try {
        imageBitmap = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    int targetHeight = 200;
                    int targetWidth = 200;

                    return Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(imageUrl))
                            //.resize(targetWidth, targetHeight)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_user)
                            .get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageBitmap;
}
```

**Firebase - Users/Drivers node**

[image: Firebase - Users/Drivers node]

Answer (score 2):

You are iterate over all the children of that driver specific node. This isn't needed at all You can directly get image url using,

```
String imageUrl = "";
if(snapshot.child("photoUrl").exists()) {
  imageUrl = snapshot.child("photoUrl").getValue().toString();
}
```

So final code in `onDataChange` method looks like below,

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            String imageUrl = "";
            If(snapshot.child("photoUrl").exists()) {
              imageUrl = snapshot.child("photoUrl").getValue().toString();
            }

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface
                    .OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            //Yes button clicked
                            Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "Confirmed!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isRiderInVehicle();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            //No button clicked
                            Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "Not Confirmed, Try Again.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RiderHome.this);
            getImageBitmapFromURL(context, imageUrl); // code below
            builder.setTitle("Driver Has Arrived")
                    .setMessage("Please proceed to vehicle.")
                    .setPositiveButton("CONFIRM", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", dialogClickListener);

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            alert.show();
    }
```

By the way the call to get bitmap from imageURL is asynchronous. So you need to wait till that code return the bitmap and then set that bitmap with imageView inside dialog.